# Design questions for RSS generating application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications, rss

I've been tasked with creating a small .net application to serve content from a DB through an RSS feed.  The content will be updated from the DB on a fixed interval (say every 30s or so).  This will be my first time working with RSS and I have somewhat limited web application skills.  However, the DBs and DA layer im pretty good so im not exactly starting from scratch.

My questions are:

1. I want to decouple the content updating process from the request servicing process.  Am I better off writing an independent windows service to handle the db-related content retrieval and XML transformation or would using a background process in a web application be fine?

   a.  If the answer is dedicated WS, will thread-blocking be an issue as the service tries to update a page at the same time the page is being served?
   b.  If the answer is BG process, is there a way to share a collection or some-type of in memory object between the background process and the main application so that on client request, the XML is generated real-time from objects in a collection?
2. So SOAP/REST WS a strong option for content delivery or am I better off with a full web application with rss.aspx?
3. For transforming the content to XML, should I use SyndicationFeed class or some form of XML template with substitution?  There are a very limited number of fields (4-8) that will be updated routinely, so the XML will be relatively tiny.

Sorry if I seem all over the place on this.  Im just trying to really think of a robust solution thats extensible and well designed.  Thanks in advance and please know I appreciated any thoughts/ideas on this project.

Answer (score 0):

I have [some experience](http://superfeedr.com) building RSS systems, so let me try to answer your questions.

1. If by decoupling you mean "generating the XML files aynschronously", then it depends on how many differents feeds you have. Based on what you describe, you'll be serving feeds based on queries to a database. If these queries have parameters, then you'll have as many different feeds that you have possible queries and generating them offline will not work. Generally, I think most people generate feeds 'on the fly' with the requests they get.
2. I'm not familiar with rss.aspx, so I can't help much :)
3. The benefit of using your own XML templates is that you'll be able extend (the X in XML!) your schema at some point with some other namespaces should you need to do that in the future.